# Mutex doesn't synchronize C++

Tags: c, winapi, concurrency, mutex

I have 2 processes. The first one sends some data to the other one, synchronizing each move.
It actually sends the data as following :

```
 Process : A sends 1
 Process : B receives 1
 Process : A sends 2
 Process : B receives 2
```

The problem is that when I run the process A it sends all the data from the beginning and I see something like:

```
 Process : A sends 1
 Process : A sends 2
 Process : A sends 3
 Process : B receives 3
```

I did as following:

```
  Process A
   HANDLE mutex;    
    mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, TEXT("mutex1"));
    if (mutex == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Create mutex error !.\n"), GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
   for (int i = 0; i < sender_length;i++) {
       WaitForSingleObject(mutex,INFINITE);
       sendToB(data);
       ReleaseMutex(mutex);
       }

     CloseHandle(mutex);
```

And the B process looks like following:

```
 Process B:

  HANDLE mutex;

    mutex = OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, TEXT("mutex1"));

    if (mutex == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Mutex error ! \n"), GetLastError());
        return 1;
      }
     for (int i = 0; i < sender_length;i++) {
           WaitForSingleObject(mutex,INFINITE);
           receiveFromA(data);
           ReleaseMutex(mutex);
           }

         CloseHandle(mutex);
```

Comment: Don't create the mutex inside the code you are trying to synchronise.

Comment: Your mental model of a mutex appears to be significantly in error. There is effectively no question here that can be answered other than to tell you that a mutex does not do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: A mutex just says only one thing can hold it at a time. It says nothing about the order in which various participants acquire it. What you've described is a perfectly valid result of this. You probably want a queue of some sort instead.

Comment: Or use waitable events instead. `A` can signal one event when it is sending data, and `B` can wait for that event before receiving. Then `A` can wait for `B` to signal another event when it has received the data, before sending new data.

Comment: You have C++ in the title, but you've tagged as C. Is this what you intended?

Comment: why not use say pipes here if you want send/receive ? mutex here no sense use. it not guarantee order of operation. only that when send and receive not run in concurrent at same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is your problem, but I think there's a good chance that it's at least a contributor: Windows locks haven't been fair for a while now. See Joe Duffy's article [Anti-convoy locks in Windows Server 2003 SP1 and Windows Vista](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/12/14/anticonvoy-locks-in-windows-server-2003-sp1-and-windows-vista/) for some details.

Specifically for mutexes Duffy says the following (highlighting added by me):

> Of course, Windows locks are still a teensy bit fair. The wait lists for mutually exclusive locks are kept in FIFO order, and the OS always wakes the thread at the front of such wait queues. ... Now when a lock becomes unowned, a FIFO waking algorithm is still used, but the lock is immediately marked as unavailable. **Another thread can sneak in and take the lock before the woken thread is even scheduled**

That other thread can be the thread that just released the lock.  In your code, the very next thing the thread that releases the mutex does is attmept to reacquire the mutex, which it's in a good position to do.

Comment: Even with fair locks, the result envisioned is not guaranteed or even particularly likely. One needs explicit synchronization in both directions to get a perfect ping pong back and forth. Generally a certain degree of buffering is offered if one is writing a pipe like thing, but you still need more than a mutex to accomplish the waits.

Comment: Using a debugger attached to both processes could confirm this hypothesis by forcing  a "ping - pong" sequence

Comment: @ZalmanStern is exactly right.  The code is broken even if the locks were completely fair.  There is nothing to guarantee that the thread that is supposed to run next will actually have reached the point where it's waiting on the mutex before the mutex is released by the other thread.